# How to Mock HTTP404 with axios-mock-adapter and custom error object

Tags: axios, jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

I have an overridden Axios function which helps me make API requests. the implementation of that function is that when the API call fails, it adds attributes in `error.customAttributes`.

```js
try {
   const data = await getMeDataPlease(param);
} catch (error) {
  if (error.customAttributes.httpErrorStatus === 404) {
    error.userError = {} // anything
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I would like to test this function `catch` code, that it correctly adds/builds `error.userError` object. for that, I am mocking Axios call as following.

```js
describe('External Apis', () => {
  it('Get me data fails', async () => {
    const axiosMock = new MockAdapter(myCustomHttpClient());
    const url = 'my-data-url-goes-here';

    axiosMock.onGet(url).reply(404, {customAttributes: {httpErrorStatus:404});
    const data = await getEnrollments('username'); // in actual method the method fails on `if (error.customAttributes.httpErrorStatus === 404)` with undefined does not have `httpErrorStatus`
    console.log('data', data);
  });
```

but I am not able to mock Axios request like that, the error object does not contain my expected `customAttributes`. Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you share your full test file?

Comment: Sure. i have upded the file.

Comment: Cool. Can you also share your custom http and the way you import it into the actual file and test file as well? Since you might have had 2 instances of http object

Comment: https://github.com/edx/frontend-platform/tree/master/src/auth

Comment: Not sure where exactly your code is but the test in the dir is now set up right by sharing the same `axios` instance between the service and the test (passing the http instance which is being used in the service to `MockAdapter` in test)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and the workaround I found is to mock with rejected promise:

```js
mock.onGet(url).reply(() => Promise.reject({
  customAttributes: {httpErrorStatus:404}
}));
```